# Line break after every three consecutive decimal numbers

Tags: regex

I have a string with data similar to the following...

> i would be 3.0 0.0 3.0 very grateful for 2.0 1.0 4.0 any assistance
>   with 4.0 2.0 6.0 this problem 3.0 1.0 0.0

I want to add a line break after the third decimal number in each part of the string, such that it looks like this:

> i would be 3.0 0.0 3.0
> very grateful for 2.0 1.0 4.0
> any assistance
>   with 4.0 2.0 6.0
> this problem 3.0 1.0 0.0

I know how to match decimal numbers, but I'm not sure how to match against three consecutive decimal numbers, which is what I need here. After the third consecutive decimal number, I'd want to insert a line break.

Thanks for any help/hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex for search:

```
(?:\b\d+\.\d+\D+){2}\d+\.\d+\b\K\s*
```

And use `"\n"` as replacement.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dH9nT7/1)

`\K` resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match

Answer (score 1):

```
\s*(.*?(?:\s+\d+(?:\.\d+)){3})
```

You can try this.Replace by `$1\n` or `\1\n`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nS2lT4/33

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to match:

```
((?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s+){3})
```

And replace with `$1\n`

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xL4tD3/4)